# Worklight Direct Update - Does it replace all not native assets or just updated ones

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Does it replace all non-native assets or just updated ones.
If only one configuration related json file requires change, then would all other files (non modified including images etc) also get downloaded to mobile client?
If answer is "Yes", then is it possible to send update which is limited to download of only modified file (or may be 1 or 2 more in order to update checksum value or other supporting jobs - but not all files) in order to provide better user experience?

Any detailed documentation of explaining how "Direct Update" works at low level.

Environment: Worklight 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Worklight 6.2 Direct Update will unpack **all** of the web resources ("non native") of the application.

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 Direct Update received some love and also supports differential updating, meaning that only changed resources will be delivered instead of all of the web resources of the application (unless the user missed the update (meaning there was an additional Direct Update after the original, which the user did not accept), in which case the specific user will get a full update instead of differential).